# Aliyun OSS to GCP Cloud Storage migration

Tags: google-cloud-storage, alibaba-cloud

I am trying to migrate files from Aliyun OSS to GCP Cloud Storage.
As I see, [Transfer service](https://cloud.google.com/storage-transfer-service?hl=en) just supports AWS and Azure Blob storage natively.

Workaround will be to use [Rclone](https://rclone.org/) for this job, but is there any other alternative?

Also, is there any better easy way to transfer files from private blob storage located in public cloud such as Aliyun to GCP cloud storage?

Comment: Alibaba Cloud supports Access/Secret keys. You can use almost any tool that supports Amazon S3. I have not tested with Google Cloud Transfer service, but if you can set the endpoint then it should work.

Comment: @JohnHanley Tried this but it ended in error.
"S3 source Bucket name violates s3 naming rules. Please check for invalid characters or leading/trailing spaces. "
Nomenclature of AWS and Aliyun buckets seems too different.